# C#-Why does this if statment removes a new line character on StreamReader's output?

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, streamreader, console.writeline

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("randomTextFile.txt");
string line = "";

while (line != null)
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();

    if (line != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

reader.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

In the above code, there is an if statment inside the while statment, even though they specify the same thing `(line != null)`. If I remove said if statment, a new line will be added after the txt file contents (instead of "11037", the console will show "11037" + an empty line).

Comment: What would `Console.WriteLine(null);` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`while`-loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx) exit condition will only be checked  when it is invoked, so at the beginning of each iteration, not everytime inside it's scope.

> MSND: the test of the while expression takes place **before each execution** of
>   the loop

You could use this loop:

```
string line;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("randomTextFile.txt"))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

You should also use the `using`-statement as shown above on every object implementing `IDisposable`. On that way it is ensured that unmanaged resources are disposed.

---

According to the `Console.WriteLine` specific question why it writes a new line even if the value is `null`, that's [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written to the standard
>   output stream.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I didn't realize that **string line = ""** before the loop was called. That would make it check if a line was null AFTER writting it out in the console all along!

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are supposed to check after you read, so try read then check.
This is what you code should look like.

```
var reader = new StreamReader("randomTextFile.txt");
var line = reader.ReadLine();

while (line != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}

reader.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

As a side note, you are using a `StreamReader` which implements `IDisposable` and you should wrap this in a `using` block.